# Looking for calendar data to import into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, calendar

I want to create a calendar date table in SQL Server for 2002 to 2011, which would minimally contain all of the dates for each year, along with whether each date is a week day or week-end day.

Any ideas on where I can find such data online? (or elsewhere)? How can I import or generate such a table?

Comment: There are a multitude of examples on how to do this. How about searching?

Comment: You can take a look at this question, for example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql

Answer (score 3):

```
set datefirst 1

;with Cal as
(
  select cast('20020101' as datetime) as dt
  union all
  select dt+1
  from Cal
  where dt < cast('20111231' as datetime)
)
select
  dt as [Date],
  case datepart(dw, dt)
    when 6 then 1
    when 7 then 1
    else 0
  end  as Weekend  
from Cal
option (maxrecursion 0)
```