# Apply week number to dates for whole weeks only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

The time is: `(m/d/yyyy) => 2009/01/04`

[image]

Using this command `using datepart(wk,'20090104')` I can get the week number (for any given date).

So :

```
SELECT datepart(wk,'20090101') //1
SELECT datepart(wk,'20090102') //1
SELECT datepart(wk,'20090103') //1
SELECT datepart(wk,'20090104') //2
```

So far so good.

The problem :

Those 3 first dates are not part of a full week, so I can't put them in a fixed 52-week chart.

Our company needs to see information about each **whole** week in the **52 weeks** of a year.  (Each year has 52 whole weeks).

[image]

So `20090101` doesn't belong to the first week of 2009 !

It belongs to the previous year (*which is irrelevant to my question*)

So I need a UDF (*I've been searching a lot, and `ISOWEEK` is not answering my needs*) which by a given `datetime`, will give me the `Week Number` (week = whole week, so partial weeks aren't considered).

Example :

```
calcweekNum ('20090101') //52 ...from the last year
calcweekNum ('20090102') //52 ...from the last year
calcweekNum ('20090103') //52 ...from the last year
calcweekNum ('20090104') //1
..
..
calcweekNum ('20090110') //1
calcweekNum ('20090111') //2
calcweekNum ('20090112') //2
...
```

Comment: Have you checked out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11320441/57611)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a different approach. All you need to supply is the year:

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2009;


DECLARE @start SMALLDATETIME;
SET @start = DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 0);

;WITH n AS
(
  SELECT TOP (366) -- in case of leap year
      d = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, @start)
    FROM sys.all_objects
),
x AS 
(
  SELECT md = MIN(d) FROM n 
    WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d) = 1 -- assuming DATEFIRST is Sunday
),
y(d,wk) AS
(
  SELECT n.d, ((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, n.d) - DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, x.md)-1)/7) + 1
  FROM n CROSS JOIN x
  WHERE n.d >= x.md
  AND n.d < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @start)
)
SELECT [date] = d, [week] = wk
FROM y WHERE wk < 53
ORDER BY [date];
```

Results:

```rexx
date        week
----------  ----
2009-01-04  1
2009-01-05  1
2009-01-06  1
2009-01-07  1
2009-01-08  1
2009-01-09  1
2009-01-10  1
2009-01-11  2
2009-01-12  2
...
2009-12-25  51
2009-12-26  51
2009-12-27  52
2009-12-28  52
2009-12-29  52
2009-12-30  52
2009-12-31  52
```

Note that week 52 won't necessarily be a full week, and that in some cases (e.g. 2012), the last day or two of the year might fall in week 53, so they're excluded.

An alternative approach is to repeat the MIN expression twice:

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2009;


DECLARE @start SMALLDATETIME;
SET @start = DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 0);

;WITH n AS
(
  SELECT TOP (366) -- in case of leap year
      d = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)-1, @start)
    FROM sys.all_objects
),
y(d,wk) AS
(
  SELECT n.d, ((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, n.d) - DATEDIFF(DAY, @start, (SELECT MIN(d) 
    FROM n WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d) = 1))-1)/7) + 1
  FROM n
  WHERE n.d >= (SELECT md = MIN(d) FROM n WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, d) = 1)
  AND n.d < DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @start)
)
SELECT [date] = d, [week] = wk
FROM y WHERE wk < 53
ORDER BY d;
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, I've just been writing T-SQL for a very long time.

Comment: +1 - Nice answer. I'm always intrigued when I see this: `DATEADD(YEAR, somevalue, 0)` and then I remember how it works :-)

Comment: @Lamak what usages with  `DATEADD(YEAR, somevalue, 0)` ?

Comment: Aaron, your critique on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11320441/57611) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function for you to calculate it on the fly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WholeWeekFromDate (
   @Date datetime
)
RETURNS tinyint
AS BEGIN
RETURN (
   SELECT DateDiff(Day, DateAdd(Year, DateDiff(Year, 0, CalcDate), 0), CalcDate) / 7 + 1
   FROM (SELECT DateAdd(Day, (DateDiff(Day, 0, @Date) + 1) / 7 * 7, 0)) X (CalcDate)
);
END;
```

I don't recommend you use it, as it may perform badly due to being called once for every row. If you absolutely must have a function to use in real queries, then convert it to an inline function returning a single column and row, and use it as so:

```
SELECT
   OtherColumns,
   (SELECT WeekNumber FROM dbo.WholeWeekFromDate(DateColumn)) WeekNumber
FROM
   YourTable;
```

This will allow it to be "inlined" in the execution plan and perform significantly better.

But even better, as others have suggested, is to use a BusinessDate table. Here's a head start on creating one for you:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.BusinessDate (
   BusinessDate date NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_BusinessDate PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   WholeWeekYear smallint NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT CK_BusinessDate_WholeWeekYear_Valid
      CHECK (WholeWeekYear BETWEEN 1900 AND 9999),
   WholeWeekNumber tinyint NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT CK_BusinessDate_WholeWeekNumber_Valid
      CHECK (WholeWeekNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 53),
   Holiday bit CONSTRAINT DF_BusinessDate_Holiday DEFAULT (0),
   Weekend bit CONSTRAINT DF_BusinessDate_Weekend DEFAULT (0),
   BusinessDay AS
      (Convert(bit, CASE WHEN Holiday = 0 AND Weekend = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) PERSISTED
);
```

And I'll even populate it from 1900-01-01 through 2617-09-22 (Is that enough for the projected life of your product? And it's only 7.8MB so don't fret over size):

```
WITH A (N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
   UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
B (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM A F, A A, A L, A C, A O, A N),
C (N) AS (SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM B),
Dates AS (
   SELECT
      N,
      DateAdd(Day, N, '18991231') Dte,
      DateAdd(Day, N / 7 * 7, '19000101') CalcDate
   FROM C
)
INSERT dbo.BusinessDate
SELECT
   Dte,
   Year(CalcDate),
   DateDiff(Day, DateAdd(Year, DateDiff(Year, 0, CalcDate), 0), CalcDate) / 7 + 1,
   0,
   (N + 6) % 7 / 5 -- calculate weekends
FROM Dates; -- 3-7 seconds or so on my VM server
```

Then join to the table on the date, and use the WholeWeekNumber column for your output. You might also consider adding a WeekNumberYear because it's going to be a tad difficult to figure out that the 52 of 2009-01-01 really belongs to 2008 without this... a strange data point in there for sure if you don't (laugh).

Example table contents:

```
BusinessDate WholeWeekYear WholeWeekNumber Holiday Weekend BusinessDay
------------ ------------- --------------- ------- ------- -----------
   1/1/2009          2008              52       0       0           1 
   1/2/2009          2008              52       0       0           1 
   1/3/2009          2008              52       0       1           0 
   1/4/2009          2009               1       0       1           0 
   1/5/2009          2009               1       0       0           1 
   1/6/2009          2009               1       0       0           1 
   1/7/2009          2009               1       0       0           1 
   1/8/2009          2009               1       0       0           1 
   1/9/2009          2009               1       0       0           1 
  1/10/2009          2009               1       0       1           0 
  1/11/2009          2009               2       0       1           0
```

If you really don't want to use this as a general business date calculation table, you can drop the last 3 columns, otherwise, update the Holiday column to 1 for company holidays.

Note: if you actually make the above table, and your access to it most often uses JOIN or WHERE conditions on a different column than `BusinessDate`, then make the primary key nonclustered and add a clustered index starting with the alternate column.

*Some of the above scripts require SQL 2005 or higher.*

Comment: I don't like the first function idea merely because as you've admitted performance will not be good when it's called for every row (and I'm not convinced your inlining trick will perform as well as you think). I agree in spirit with the calendar table idea but in this case I think generating a specific year's calendar on the fly is sufficient, and there didn't seem to be any need for holiday / weekend / business day etc. Also I think your week number of 52 for 1/1/2009 is not correct if I understood the requirements right - those dates would not belong in any whole week for 2008 or 2009.

Answer (score 2):

It would be relatively easy to setup a custom calendar table with one row for each date of the year in it, and then have other fields that will allow you to rollup however you want. I do this when I have clients using varying calendars, i.e. fiscal years, and it makes the query logic very simple.

Then you just join date-to-date and get the week-number that you want.

```
date       | reporting year | reporting week
-----------|----------------|---------------
2009-01-01 | 2008           | 52
2009-01-02 | 2008           | 52
2009-01-03 | 2008           | 52
2009-01-04 | 2009           | 01
2009-01-05 | 2009           | 01
etc.
```

and then to use it ( for example to get total sales rollup by your custom weeks, didn't validated my sql):

```
select reporting_year, reporting_month, sum(sales) 
  from sales
  inner join custom_date_table cdt on cdt.sysdate = sales.sysdate
  group by reporting_year, reporting_month
  where report_year=2009
```

Comment: so the table will have about 365 records ?

Comment: yes, and you add to it each year (or setup many years all at once if it is known ahead of time). It is the most flexible solution, not just for your case, but for many others as well that involves custom date rollups.

Comment: what will be the first value ? can you supply please 3 lines ?

Comment: First primary key value would be the oldest date you have (or expect to have) in your table. There will be one row for each date, and perhaps multiple columns in your case - one for the year that the date should roll into, and one for the week it should roll into.

Comment: thanks ! ok but how am i gonna find this value ?http://i.stack.imgur.com/6un6S.jpg

Comment: oh.... youre saying to include the prev ones.... but how can i know that they represent value from older year ?

Comment: apprecate your help , but how from `2009-01-01`  - i can get to  `2008` ? how would i know its belong to prev year ?

Comment: look at the edits to my post, you add two columns besides the date one for the reporting year, and one for the reporting month.

Comment: Yes, set it up manually. You could do 20 years in about 15 minutes in an excel spreadsheet, and then import it to SQL table - that is what I would do. If there was a simple function to do it, you wouldn't need the custom rollup table.

Comment: You can do it much quicker without bothering to use Excel. You can use DATEADD against a numbers table or ROW_NUMBER() from a cross join of any number of system tables, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE;
SET @StartDate = '20120101';

WITH Calendar AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS DateValue
        ,DATEPART(DW, @StartDate) AS DayOfWeek
        ,CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, @StartDate) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS WeekNumber
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, DateValue)
        ,DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(d, 1, DateValue)) AS DayOfWeek
        ,CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 7 THEN WeekNumber + 1 ELSE WeekNumber END
    FROM Calendar 
    WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, DateValue) = DATEPART(YEAR, @StartDate)
)
SELECT DateValue, WeekNumber
FROM Calendar
WHERE WeekNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 52
    AND DATEPART(YEAR, DateValue) = DATEPART(YEAR, @StartDate)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: exluding the first 3 dates will be excellent. ( so it will give me a one atomic year info). can you please elaborate /

Comment: See the updated answer.  Did you want to include the dates for week 52 that run into the next year too?  Let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: no... do you mean the last row in `20120101`  input ? there is week 53 there... it should be shown

Comment: Are you saying it *should* be shown (as it is now) or it should *not* be shown?  If it should *not* be shown I'll update the answer to remove week 53.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a UDF, use a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql) instead, then you can define week numbers exactly as your company requires and simply query them from the table, which will be much easier and possibly much faster than using a UDF.

A calendar table has numerous uses in SQL (search this site or Google) so you should probably create it anyway.

Answer (score -1):

There is no good answer for this.

A year is NOT 52 weeks long.

It is 52 weeks *and one day* in normal years, and 52 weeks *and two days* in leap years.

Comment: i can handle those little bias.  but when a company wants to see 52 weeks - i must  nring each date ( with a little bias) to its [1..52] week

Comment: So the company doesn't care if the year starts on a Monday and you completely ignore the first 6 days? Maybe not following a calendar week is a better approach than pretending everything that happened in the 2nd week happened in the first, everything that happened in the 3rd week happened in the second, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no.:) there is 52 number on the Xaxis. 52.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what 52 means. Repeating it is not going to make me understand your point any better. But surely there are smart people in your company who know that there aren't *exactly* 52 weeks in a year.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i understnad what your saying but i have to find a way to set a date to its whole week number