# Queries for row of variables and storing into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server `select` statement which is inserting data in a created table.

Right now I have to define all parameters and run the statement for each of them. To be more efficient I would like to run the statement like multiple times for a row of some consecutive days, e.g. for all days between `2013-31-12` and `2014-02-19`.

At the end I want to have the resulting data in one table with different timestamps in the defined `timestamp` column (let's say the defined variable).

Right now I working with this:

```
DECLARE @historicalDate DATETIME

SELECT  @historicalDate = '2013-31-12'#

SELECT * ....
rest...
into #data
```

I know how to do it in C or MATLAB. I would just use a for loop and define a running variable to run the statement and store it in a table.

But how to handle in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can run While loops in SQL. Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx for syntax.

So for your case, something like:

```
WHILE (SELECT datetime FROM historicalDate) < '2014-02-19')
{
   //your code to update datebase
}
```

Comment: Don't use WHILE loops in SQL Server! SQL Server is a **set-based, relational** system - use **sets of data** and don't fall back into RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) procedural processing .....

Comment: This is something I have heard a lot of time. But how to run the statement for sets of data? It is possible to make an array of dates? And then use this array as input?

Comment: @user3165675: anything "array" in SQL Server is a **table** - that's how to hold multiple rows of data (real, temporary, table variable)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert all rows for a defined date range - use something like this:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME

SET @FromDate = '20131231'   -- use the robust ISO-8601 format here to avoid issues!
SET @ToDate = '20140219'

SELECT (list of columns)
INTO #data(list of columns)
WHERE TimestampColumn >= @FromDate 
  AND TimestampColumn <= @ToDate
```

This does your whole processing in a single, set-based operation - nice and easy

Or what exactly is it that you're trying to achieve if this doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: I think this will not work in my case. I have to "backtest" something for the past. So I have to write an code that is trying to catch the as-is status for each day in the past. Propably I really have to use loops...

Comment: You can still do `CASE` and `IF` statements in SQL as well.  Loops are a last resort for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a calendar table and join the calendar table for the specified date range to your query. 
If you haven't got a calendar table see: [How to create a Calender table for 100 years in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql)

You would then be able to do something along the lines of:

```
Select <fields>
FROM <YourTable> T
CROSS JOIN CALENDAR C
WHERE C.DATE BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate
```