# sql calculate business hours for weekdays by opening and closing hours range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I want to calculate the business hour between given date range (Opening day and closing day)

for example: Business working hours

> `ID        WeekName     OpeningHour    ClosingHour`
>
> `01        Monday       8.00AM        4.00PM`
>
> `02        Tuesday      8.00AM        4.00PM`
>
> `03        Wednesday    8.00AM        4.00PM`
>
> `04        Thursday     8.00AM        4.00PM`
>
> `05        Friday       8.00AM        4.00PM`

If I give a date range for example 
Opening day: 01/04/2014 09.00AM 
Closing day: 03/04/2014 14.00 AM

I want to calculate the business hour from given date range
there are 3 days between given range

01/04/2014

02/04/2014

03/04/2014

first I want to check the day name and calculate the hour from business hour (from above table) .

01/04/2014 - Tuesday

02/04/2014 - Wednesday

03/04/2014 - Thursday

Results I expecting:

> `GivenDate    DayID    DayName    DateDiff`
>
> `01/04/2014     01        Tuesday         7`
>
> `02/04/2014     02        Wednesday       8`
>
> `03/04/2014     03        Thursday        6`

Comment: Did you do some research on the web? I think you can find plenty of articles related to this problem.

Comment: i did the research i didn't reach the expected result !!!
if i am getting result i didn't ask question here !!!

Comment: Will the start and end of the range that you're querying for always fall within a single week? Or could they span (one or more?) weekends also?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  the days can be span thought more week and can also include the weekends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on Stackoverflow, it is generally frowned upon to just ask a question, expecting others to do your work for you. You should at least show some minimum effort, for example some SQL that you have tried out so far.

That said, here's the query that will return what you want. This query works even if you don't have a Date (Calendar) table, as it generates a sequence of numbers from a system table. These numbers are then, in turn, added to the startdate, to return one record for each day in the interval:

```
SELECT * INTO #WorkingHours 
FROM (VALUES (1, 'Monday', '08:00', '16:00')
    ,(2, 'Tuesday', '08:00', '16:00')
    ,(3, 'Wednesday', '08:00', '16:00')
    ,(4, 'Thursday', '08:00', '16:00')
    ,(5, 'Friday', '08:00', '16:00'))
E(DayId, DayName, OpeningHour, ClosingHour)

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-04-01 09:00:00'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2014-04-03 14:00:00'

SELECT [GivenDate], [DayID], [DayName],
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, CASE WHEN @StartDate > [OpeningDateTime] THEN @StartDate ELSE [OpeningDateTime] END, 
        CASE WHEN @EndDate < [ClosingDateTime] THEN @EndDate ELSE [ClosingDateTime] END) AS [DateDiff]
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(@StartDate + n - 1 AS DATE) AS [GivenDate]
        , n AS [DayID]
        , DATENAME(dw, @StartDate + n - 1) AS [DayName]
        , CAST(CAST(CAST(@StartDate + n - 1 AS DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + OpeningHour AS DateTime) AS OpeningDateTime
        , CAST(CAST(CAST(@StartDate + n - 1 AS DATE) AS VARCHAR) + ' ' + ClosingHour AS DateTime) AS ClosingDateTime
    FROM    
        -- Numbers, for expanding the date range:
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) n FROM sys.all_objects) Numbers
    INNER JOIN #WorkingHours ON DayName = DATENAME(dw, @StartDate + n - 1)
    WHERE Numbers.n <= DATEDIFF(d, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1
) SubQuery
```

And here is the resulting output:

[image]

Comment: thnx for very much for help me its working and have new SQL stuff for learn 
i cant add reputation point for you because i dont have enough points sorry for that

Comment: @dan i got error Invalid column name 'number'. how i can fix it

Comment: Replace `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)` with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id)`. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple if you have Date(Calendar) table. First thing you join your start and end date to calendar table to get days. Than you just compare those `DATENAME` to what you have in your table. Below is the sample code using table variable and `DATE` (calendar) table.

```
DECLARE @BusHours TABLE
    (
     ID INT
    ,DayOfWeekName VARCHAR(10)
    ,OpeningHour VARCHAR(7)
    ,ClosingHOur VARCHAR(7)
    )

INSERT INTO @BusHours
        ( ID, DayOfWeekName, OpeningHour, ClosingHour )
    VALUES  ( 1, 'Monday', '08:00AM', '04:00PM' )
    ,       ( 2, 'Tuesday', '08:00AM', '04:00PM' )
    ,       ( 3, 'Wednesday', '08:00AM', '04:00PM' )
    ,       ( 4, 'Thursday', '08:00AM', '04:00PM' )
    ,       ( 5, 'Friday', '08:00AM', '04:00PM' )

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '04/01/2014 09:00AM'
   ,@EndDate DATETIME = '04/03/2014 14:00PM'

SELECT d.Date_Dt AS GivenDate
       ,b.ID AS DayID
       ,b.DayOfWeekName AS DayName
       ,CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @StartDate) = b.DayOfWeekName
             THEN DATEDIFF(hh, @StartDate,
                           CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @StartDate, 101) + ' ' + b.ClosingHour))
             WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @EndDate) = b.DayOfWeekName
             THEN DATEDIFF(hh, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @EndDate, 101) + ' ' + b.OpeningHour), @EndDate)
             ELSE DATEDIFF(hh, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2014' + ' ' + b.OpeningHour),
                           CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2014' + ' ' + b.ClosingHour))
        END AS HoursOperation
    FROM dbo.Date AS d
    JOIN @BusHours AS b
        ON DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d.Date_Dt) = b.DayOfWeekName
    WHERE d.Date_Dt >= CONVERT(DATE, @startDate)
        AND d.Date_Dt <= CONVERT(DATE, @EndDate)
```

Table definition for `[Date]` table at my work. Not everyone has the same implementation of it, but if you search around you can find many scripts to generate it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Date]
    (
     [Date_Id] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[Date_Dt] [date] NULL
    ,[Date_Nm] [varchar](9) NULL
    ,[DayType_Cd] [varchar](7) NULL
    ,[DayofWeek_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[DayofWeek_Nm] [varchar](10) NULL
    ,[DayofMonth_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[DayofYear_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Week_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Week_Nm] [varchar](5) NULL
    ,[WeekFirstDay_Dt] [date] NULL
    ,[WeekLastDay_Dt] [date] NULL
    ,[WeekofYear_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Month_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Month_6_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Month_Nm] [varchar](6) NULL
    ,[MonthFull_Nm] [varchar](9) NULL
    ,[MonthLastDay_Dt] [date] NULL
    ,[MonthofYear_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Quarter_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Quarter_Nm] [varchar](5) NULL
    ,[QuarterofYear_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Year_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[Year_Nm] [varchar](4) NULL
    ,[FYDayofWeek_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[FYWeek_Nbr] [int] NULL
    ,[FYWeek_Nm] [varchar](5) NULL
    ,[FYWeekFirstDay_Dt] [date] NULL
    ,[FYWeekLastDay_Dt] [date] NULL
    ,[FYWeekofYear_Nbr] [int] NULL
    )
```

Comment: what is the mean of DATE (calendar) table. ?

Comment: It is just a table that has random date information. Like having every day listed from Jan 1 to Dec 31 for many years. Plus it has columns populated for `DAY()` , `YEAR()`, `MONTH()` and many other date function. This way instead of generating those values on the fly you are able to just look up from column. I updated answer with `Date` table definition.

Comment: @DjAdmin here is question on SO that has scripts for generating Calendar table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql

Comment: thnx everyone for the answer i could write my own calculation function table

Comment: @littledragon can you share your table schema? i am on the same boat and need help to design database. Thanks in advance