# Finding monthly average number of records created in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Below is the query to find monthly average of number of records created.
**CREATED DATE IS TIMESTAMP**

```
select year,month, (ymcount/maxmonthdays) as monthaverage ymcount  from (
select year,month,maxmonthdays, count(1) ymcount  from (
SELECT year(created) as year, MONTHNAME(created) as month,
day(date(date(created))-(day(date(created)) -1) days + 1 month -1 day)  as maxmonthdays 
FROM tablename )
group by year,month,maxmonthdays );
```

**NOTE:** To find max number of days in a month, I have used below command.

```
day(date(date(created))-(day(date(created)) -1) days + 1 month -1 day)  as maxmonthdays
```

One can use last_day function supported after DB2 version 9.7 onwards, I m using version 9.5.

Comment: What is your question?  Also, can you assume that records are created every day or is the problem to count the number of days in the month?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: Your query will also ignore any indices on `created` (due to the use of the `YEAR(...)` and `MONTHNAME(...)` functions), making this slow for tables of real size.  Do you have a [Calendar Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql) (the question/answer is mostly for SQL Server, but the technique still applies)?  If not you can generate one on-the-fly for a range...