# Creating index on timestamp column for query which uses year function

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization, query-tuning

I have a `HISTORY` table with 9 million records. I need to find year-wise, month-wise records created. I was using query no 1, However it timed out several times.

```
SELECT 
    year(created) as year, 
    MONTHNAME(created) as month, 
    count(*) as ymcount  
FROM 
    HISTORY 
GROUP BY 
    year(created), MONTHNAME(created);
```

I decided to add `where year(created)`, this time the query took 30 mins (yes it takes so long) to execute.

```
SELECT 
    year(created) as year, 
    MONTHNAME(created) as month, 
    count(*) as ymcount  
FROM 
    HISTORY 
WHERE 
    year(created) = 2010
GROUP BY  
    year(created), MONTHNAME(created) ;
```

I was planning to add an index on `created` timestamp column, however before doing so, I need the opinion (since its going to take a long time to index such a huge table).

Will adding an index on `created(timestamp)` column improve performance, considering year function is used on the column?

Comment: What database system do you use?

Comment: Its db2.. I Forgot to tag.. Any ways it's should be a common question.

Comment: Yes, but with the proper tag, you might get better answers than without. And it is way better than the wrong [tag:sql-server] tag.

Comment: The types of DB2 indexes available are platform dependent.  Are you referring to DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS?

Answer (score 4):

An index won't really help because you have formed the query such that it must perform a complete table scan, index or no index. You have to form the `where` clause so it is in the form:

```
where field op constant
```

where `field` is, of course, your field; `op` is `= <= => <> between in`, etc. and constant is either a direct constant, `42`, or an operation that can be executed once and the result cached, `getdate()`.

Like this:

```
where created >= DateFromParts( @year, 1, 1 )
  and created < DateFromParts( @year + 1, 1, 1 )
```

The `DateFromParts` function will generate a value which remains in effect for the duration of the query. If `created` is indexed, now the optimizer will be able to seek to exactly where the correct dates start and tell when the last date in the range has been processed and it can stop. You can keep `year(created)` everywhere else -- just get rid of it from the `where` clause.

This is called sargability and you can google all kinds of good information on it.

P.S. This is in Sql Server format but you should be able to calculate "beginning of specified year" and "beginning of year after specified year" in whatever DBMS you're using.

Comment: are you sure the query will execute? Since I m using count function, all there other select should be a part of group Clause

Comment: I don't have access to db2, but here is how it works in Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f408/1/0 If you notice, the only thing you are grouping on are different manifestations of /created/ so that is all you need in the WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

An index will be used, when it helps narrow down the number of rows read.

It will also be used, when it avoids reading the table at all. This is the case, when the index contains all the columns referenced in the query.

In your case the only column referenced is `created`, so adding an index on this column should help reducing the necessary reads and improve the overall runtime of your query. However, if `created` is the only column in the table, the index won't change anything in the first query, because it doesn't reduce the number of pages to be read.

Even with a large table, you can test, if an index makes a difference. You can copy only part of the rows to a new table and compare the execution plans on the new table with and without an index, e.g.

```sql
insert into testhistory
select *
from history
fetch first 100000 rows only
```

Answer (score 1):

You want what's known as a [Calendar Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5635594/812837) (the particular example uses SQL Server, but the solution should be adaptable).  Then, you want lots of indices on it (since writes are few, and this is a primary dimension table for analysis).

Assuming you have a minimum Calendar Table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (isoDate     DATE,
                       dayOfMonth  INTEGER,
                       month       INTEGER,
                       year        INTEGER);
```

... with an index over [`dayOfMonth`, `month`, `year`, `isoDate`], your query can be re-written like this:

```
SELECT Calendar.year, Calendar.month,
       COUNT(*) AS ymCount
FROM Calendar
JOIN History
  ON History.created >= Calendar.isoDate
     AND History.created < Calendar.isoDate + 1 MONTH
WHERE Calendar.dayOfMonth = 1
GROUP BY Calendar.year, Calendar.month
```

The `WHERE Calendar.dayOfMonth = 1` is automatically limiting results to 12-per-year.  The start of the range is trivially located with the index (given the SARGable data), and the end of the range as well (yes, doing math on a column generally disqualifies indices... on the side the math is used.  If the optimizer is at all smart it's going to going to gen a virtual intermediate table containing the start/end of range).

So, index-based (and likely *index-only*) access for the query.  Learn to love indexed dimension tables, that can be used for range queries (Calendar Tables being one of the most useful).

Comment: This suggestion does not works for me, I tried several ways, ANd getting below error                                                 *Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601*                                                     ' SELECT calendar.yearno, calendar.monthno, COUNT(*) AS ymCount FROM calendar JOIN History ON History.created >= calendar.isoDate AND History.created < calendar.isoDate + 1 MONTH WHERE calendar.dayofmonth = 1 GROUP BY calendar.yearno, calendar.monthno;'

Comment: If the Calendar table's granulation is one day, you should join on `... AND History.created < Calendar.isoDate + 1 DAY` rather than `... + 1 MONTH`, or you'll likely get Cartesian products as a result of the join.

Comment: @Vinayak - `-104` is usually DB2's way of saying something is missing.  Do you actually have a calendar table?  If you don't, you can create a virtual one with a CTE.  Otherwise, the error message should include more information about what's missing/wrong.

Comment: @AndriyM Well, I'd hope the grain would be 1 day.  Otherwise `WHERE Calendar.dayOfMonth = 1` would be a little silly.  `History.created` is a timestamp, so I need some sort of range, as I don't know the exact values.

Comment: Ah, yes, you've got the filter on `dayOfMonth` as well. Sorry, I overlooked that (silly me).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using SQL Server based on your tags.

Yes, the index will make your query faster.

I recommend only using the 'created' column as a key for the index and to not include any additional columns from the History table because they will be unused and only result in more reads than what is necessary.

And of course, be mindful when you create indexes on tables that have a lot of INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE activity as your new index will make these actions more expensive when being performed on the table.

Comment: Looks like the OP didn't add that SQL Server tag themselves. Based on `monthname` might be access?

Comment: Actually probably db2 from their previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

As been stated before, in your case, an index won't be used because the index is created on the column 'created' and you are querying on 'year(created)'.

What you can do is add two generated columns year_gen = year(create) and month_gen = MONTHNAME(created) to your table and index these two columns. The DB2 Query Optimizer will automatically use these two generated columns and it will also use the indices created on these columns.

The code should be something like (but not 100% sure since I have no DB2 to test)

```
SET INTEGRITY FOR HISTORY OFF CASCADE DEFERRED @
ALTER TABLE HISTORY ADD COLUMN YEAR_GEN SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(CREATE)), 
ADD COLUMN MONTH_GEN VARCHAR(20) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (YEAR(CREATE)) @
SET INTEGRITY FOR HISTORY IMMEDIATE CHECKED FORCE GENERATED @
CREATE INDEX HISTORY_YEAR_IDX ON HISTORY YEAR_GEN ASC CLUSTER @
CREATE INDEX HISTORY_MONTH_IDX ON HISTORY YEAR_GEN ASC @
```

Just a sidenote: the `set integrity off` is mandatory to add generated columns. Your table is inaccessible untill you reset the integrity to `checked` and you force the re-calculation of the generated columns (this might take a while in your case). 
Setting integrity off without `cascade deferred` will set every table with a foreign key to the HISTORY table to OFF too. You will have to manually reset the integrity of these tables too. If I remember correctly, using `cascade deferred` in combination with incomming foreign keys may cause DB2 to set the integrity of your table to 'checked by user'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We have not considered the option earlier considering it will be too slow to alter the table which is having more then 9 milion records. Also all the DML execution will be slow.

Comment: I you can not afford a reasonable downtime, then this is indeed not the best way to do because it'll take a while to recheck all integrities.