# Get data for past 7days and if no data for particular day return 0

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I would like to get data for the past 1week(7 days), with all days included. When there is no data for particular day, a zero should be returned.

This is what i have so far

```
"SELECT DATE(date) AS created_date, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount " +
"FROM milk_collection " +
"WHERE DATE(date) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY) " +
"GROUP BY created_date";
```

The problem is this query does not return zero(0) if no records for that day are found.

Comment: Could you present some information, like a case showing the state of you tables, and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jim Garrison for his guide, i was able to come up with a query that does exactly what i want. Hope this post will help someone with similar problem and save them time.

SQL

```
"SELECT DATE(D) AS temporary_date, SUM(IFNULL(quantity,0)) AS total_amount, DATE(date) AS created_date "+ 
"FROM "+ 
   "( SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL D DAY) AS D "+ 
    " FROM (SELECT 0 as D "+ 
              "UNION SELECT 1 "+ 
              "UNION SELECT 2 "+ 
              "UNION SELECT 3 "+ 
              "UNION SELECT 4 "+ 
              "UNION SELECT 5 "+ 
              "UNION SELECT 6 ) AS D ) AS D "+ 
"LEFT JOIN milk_collection ON DATE(date) = date(D) "+ 
"GROUP BY temporary_date ORDER BY D ASC ";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic application for a "[calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635628/18157)".  To get zero values for certain key values you need to ensure those key values appear in a table that you can left-join to the values table.

Create a table containing one row per date:

```
create table calendar ( cal_date date );
```

Then populate it with all dates in the range you're interested in.  Finally  left-join it to `milk_collection` on the date column in your query.  This will guarantee you have at least one row per date in the selected range, with null in the `quantity` column for dates having no data.

Comment: Or just handle the logic of missing dates in your application level code

Answer (score -1):

Try this, I am not sure if this works as I am not with my system that has MySQL installation

```
"SELECT DATE(date) AS created_date, SUM(IFNULL(quantity,0)) AS total_amount " +
"FROM milk_collection " +
"WHERE DATE(date) > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 30 DAY) " +
"GROUP BY created_date";
```

Comment: that will only return 0 when records are available but holds null, not when records are not available like in my case