# Checking for rows relating to previous days which might not exist

Tags: t-sql

I am having some trouble in my check of whether or not I received prices yesterday for let´s say - my apples.

The tricky part is that in the table where prices are stored, there won´t be any row relating to yesterday if I did not get prices yesterday. So how can I make my check everyday if I want to be sure that the day before I got some prices?

Comment: You could use a [calendar table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql) and join to this so that you have a record for each distinct day, just some will not have any records in your prices table and so will return a `NULL` value which you can `ISNULL()` to some other value.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Calendar` table (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql) for example) with a field called `Date` and making some assumptions about your data structure:

```
SELECT c.[Date], 
       ISNULL(p.Prices,'No Prices')
FROM Calendar c
LEFT JOIN Prices p ON c.[Date] = p.[Date]
```

Your question is not very clear, but it actually might even be as simple as just checking for the presence of a row for the previous day, rather than reporting across all dates (in this case I consider there are multiple products):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    prod.Product,
    CASE WHEN prev.Product IS NULL 
         THEN 'No Prices for yesterday' 
         ELSE 'Prices recorded for yesterday'
    END AS PricesYesterday
FROM Prices prod
LEFT JOIN Prices prev ON prev.Product = prod.Product
                      AND prev.[Date] = dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0) - 1
```