# How to combine multiple SELECTs into a single SELECT by a common column in (BigQuery) SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given I have multiple tables in BigQuery, hence I have multiple SQL-statements that gives me "the number of X per day". For example:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F",timestamp) AS day, COUNT(*) as installs
FROM database.table1
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC
```

Which would give the result:

```
| day        | installs |
-------------------------
| 2017-01-01 | 11       |
| 2017-01-02 | 22       |
etc
```

Another statement:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F",timestamp) AS day, COUNT(*) as uninstalls
FROM database.table2
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC
```

Which would give the result:

```
| day        | uninstalls |
---------------------------
| 2017-01-02 | 22         |
| 2017-01-03 | 33         |
etc
```

Another statement:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F",timestamp) AS day, COUNT(*) as cases
FROM database.table3
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day ASC
```

Which would give the result:

```
| day        | cases |
----------------------
| 2017-01-01 | 11    |
| 2017-01-03 | 33    |
etc
```

etc

Now I need to combine all these into a single `SELECT` statement that gives the following results:

```
| day        | installs | uninstalls | cases |
----------------------------------------------
| 2017-01-01 | 11       | 0          | 11    |
| 2017-01-02 | 22       | 22         | 0     |
| 2017-01-03 | 0        | 33         | 33    |
etc
```

Is this even possible?

Or what's the closest SQL-statement I can write that would give me a similar result?

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Yes thats entirely possible, simply join them together on `timestamp`. By the way, I hope in reality you have more functional tablenames, and it is not a good idea to name an attribute `timestamp` as that is a keyword.

Comment: Join by timestamp? The timestamp is actually a timestamp tho, down to ms, so I am not sure if joining on timestamp is the best idea?

Comment: Well, just join it by `FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F",timestamp)` then

Comment: I am unsure how the JOIN syntax should be.

Comment: This is no efficient way to do this at Big Query side. JOIN on Big Query table is very heavy operation and will cost you more. and even takes a lot time to do so. Better move it away in java layer or avoid to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(min_day) AS min_day, MAX(max_day) AS max_day
    FROM (
      SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) AS min_day, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) AS max_day FROM `database.table1` UNION ALL
      SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) AS min_day, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) AS max_day FROM `database.table2` UNION ALL
      SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) AS min_day, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) AS max_day FROM `database.table3`
    )
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_day, max_day, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS day
)
SELECT 
  c.day AS day, 
  IFNULL(SUM(installs), 0) AS installs,
  IFNULL(SUM(uninstalls), 0) AS uninstalls,
  IFNULL(SUM(cases),0) AS cases  
FROM calendar AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) day, COUNT(1) installs   FROM `database.table1` GROUP BY day) t1 ON t1.day = c.day
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) day, COUNT(1) uninstalls FROM `database.table2` GROUP BY day) t2 ON t2.day = c.day
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) day, COUNT(1) cases      FROM `database.table3` GROUP BY day) t3 ON t3.day = c.day
GROUP BY day
HAVING installs + uninstalls + cases > 0
-- ORDER BY day
```

Please note: you are using timestamp as a column name which is not the best practice as it is keyword, so in my example i leave your naming but consider to change this!

You can test / play this solution with below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `database.table1` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01' AS timestamp, 1 AS installs  
  UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01', 22 
),
`database.table2` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2016-12-01' AS timestamp, 1 AS installs  UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 
),
`database.table3` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01' AS timestamp, 1 AS installs  UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-01', 22 UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-10', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 UNION ALL  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2017-01-02', 22 
),
calendar AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(min_day) AS min_day, MAX(max_day) AS max_day
    FROM (
      SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) AS min_day, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) AS max_day FROM `database.table1` UNION ALL
      SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) AS min_day, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) AS max_day FROM `database.table2` UNION ALL
      SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) AS min_day, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) AS max_day FROM `database.table3`
    )
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_day, max_day, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS day
)
SELECT 
  c.day AS day, 
  IFNULL(SUM(installs), 0) AS installs,
  IFNULL(SUM(uninstalls), 0) AS uninstalls,
  IFNULL(SUM(cases),0) AS cases  
FROM calendar AS c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) day, COUNT(1) installs   FROM `database.table1` GROUP BY day) t1 ON t1.day = c.day
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) day, COUNT(1) uninstalls FROM `database.table2` GROUP BY day) t2 ON t2.day = c.day
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DATE(timestamp) day, COUNT(1) cases      FROM `database.table3` GROUP BY day) t3 ON t3.day = c.day
GROUP BY day
HAVING installs + uninstalls + cases > 0
ORDER BY day
```

Comment: great! if not yet - consider voting up :o)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a self-contained example that might help to get you started. It uses two dummy tables, `InstallEvents` and `UninstallEvents`, which contain timestamps for the respective actions. It creates a common table expression called `StartAndEnd` that computes the minimum and maximum dates for these events in order to decide which dates to aggregate over, then unions the contents of the `InstallEvents` and `UninstallEvents`, counting the events for each day.

```
WITH InstallEvents AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2017-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 100)) AS x
),
UninstallEvents AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2017-01-02 00:00:00', INTERVAL 2 * x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 50)) AS x
),
StartAndEnd AS (
  SELECT MIN(DATE(timestamp)) AS min_date, MAX(DATE(timestamp)) AS max_date
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM InstallEvents UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM UninstallEvents
  )
)
SELECT
  day,
  COUNTIF(is_install AND DATE(timestamp) = day) AS installs,
  COUNTIF(NOT is_install AND DATE(timestamp) = day) AS uninstalls
FROM (
  SELECT *, true AS is_install
  FROM InstallEvents UNION ALL
  SELECT *, false
  FROM UninstallEvents
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
    (SELECT min_date FROM StartAndEnd),
    (SELECT max_date FROM StartAndEnd)
  )) AS day
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```

If you know what the start and end dates are in advance, you can hard-code them in the query instead and then omit the `StartAndEnd` CTE:

```
WITH InstallEvents AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2017-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 100)) AS x
),
UninstallEvents AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2017-01-02 00:00:00', INTERVAL 2 * x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 50)) AS x
)
SELECT
  day,
  COUNTIF(is_install AND DATE(timestamp) = day) AS installs,
  COUNTIF(NOT is_install AND DATE(timestamp) = day) AS uninstalls
FROM (
  SELECT *, true AS is_install
  FROM InstallEvents UNION ALL
  SELECT *, false
  FROM UninstallEvents
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2017-01-01', '2017-01-04')) AS day
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day;
```

To see the events in the sample data, use a query that unions the contents:

```
WITH InstallEvents AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2017-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 100)) AS x
),
UninstallEvents AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD('2017-01-02 00:00:00', INTERVAL 2 * x HOUR) AS timestamp
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 50)) AS x
)
SELECT timestamp, true AS is_install
FROM InstallEvents UNION ALL
SELECT timestamp, false
FROM UninstallEvents;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with bigquery, so this is probably not going to be a copy-paste answer.

You'll first have to build a calander table to make sure you have all dates. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calender-table-for-100-years-in-sql) an example for sql server. There are probably examples for bigquery available as well. The following assumes a `Calander` table with `Date` attribute in `timestamp`.

Once you have your calander table you can join all your tables to that:

```
SELECT      FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F",C.Date) AS day
,           COUNT(T1.DATE(T1.TIMESTAMP)) AS installs --Here you could also use your FORMAT_TIMESTAMP
,           COUNT(T1.DATE(T2.TIMESTAMP)) AS uninstalls
FROM        Calander C
LEFT JOIN   database.table1 T1
        ON  DATE(T1.TIMESTAMP) = DATE(C.Date) --Convert to date to remove times, you could also use your FORMAT_TIMESTAMP
LEFT JOIN   database.table2 T2
        ON  DATE(T2.TIMESTAMP) = DATE(C.Date)
GROUP BY    day
ORDER BY    day ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and I wished it was so easy. However, as you can see in my question, each "sub-select" has a order by, etc. Here is a real example of a left join I have tried https://pastebin.com/B6usyvpf but it complains on that "day" is unknown. Good attempt though.

Comment: The error about unknown day is because it doesn't know the alias yet. So you'll have to be fully explicit: `ON acq_adult_day = FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F",timestamp)`