# what is the SQL query to get all dates list from specific date to today date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get all dates from 01-01-2016 to todays date.

Example:

```
01-01-2016
02-01-2016
03-01-2016
.
.
.
01-02-2016
.
.
.
17-11-2017
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Search for `calendar table`, there are many examples online

Comment: I don't think you make some research before asking the question. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Calendar table for 100 years in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql)

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make use of common table expression for achieving this and it is one of the fastest way to do it

```
;WITH cte 
 as
(
  SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'01-01-2016') as DateCol
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,1,DateCol))  FROM CTE
  WHERE DATEADD(DAY,1,DateCol) <= '11-17-2017'
 )

SELECT * FROM CTE 
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: This is the method I use more often than not, however be aware that iterative ctes tend not to be very efficient.  I've used the approach above to populate a table of dates, and then a job to refresh at midnight every night.  May seem like overkill, but depends on how often you hit the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *FROM Table_Name 
 WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,date_column,111) >=CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@From_Date,111) and  CONVERT(NVARCHAR,date_column,111) <=CONVERT( NVarchar, @TO_Date, 111)
```

Comment: Could you add a little explanation rather than just code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a numbers table for this to work..

```
select dateadd(day,Number,'01-01-2016') from numbers
where 
dateadd(day,Number,'01-01-2016')<=getdate()
```

To create  numbers table

```
USE Model
GO

CREATE TABLE Numbers
(
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
        WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
)

INSERT INTO Numbers
SELECT
    (a.Number * 256) + b.Number AS Number
FROM 
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE 
            type = 'P'
            AND number <= 255
    ) a (Number),
    (
        SELECT number
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE 
            type = 'P'
            AND number <= 255
    ) b (Number)
GO
```

**References:**
http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have understand from your requirement. Check below query.

=========================================

declare @date datetime='2016-01-01'

declare @tbl table
(alldate date)

while (@date<=GETDATE())
begin
insert into @tbl
select @date

set @date=@date+1

if @date=GETDATE()
begin
break;
end
end

## select  * from @tbl