# Is is possible to add a LOOP inside a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, counter

I have a calendar table which days may be filled with meetings; my main SQL returns these results :

```
DAY  | MEETINGS 
--------------
20   |    2
21   |    2
25   |    1
```

I'm trying to find a way to have ALL days of the month listed in the results, and the idea is to try something like this :

```
SELECT (@day := @day + 1) AS `Day` FROM (SELECT @day := 0) AS `Month`;
```

and add it in the proper way inside the main SQL, but it is not the right answer I'm expecting, so I'm asking if there is a way to put a do/loop/while command INSIDE the SELECT statement, something like this :

```
SELECT (DO @day := @day + 1 UNTIL @day <= 31) AS `Day` FROM (SELECT @day := 0) AS `Month`;
```

Comment: Do you have a calendar days table available?  If not, I would create one.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql You `create` the calendar table and `join` the dates from your other table on it.

Comment: A `CASE` statement should suffice I think.

Comment: alas the CASE works only on collected records and it can't generate rows without having a source to link to. 

i want to have the missing days without any table as source and list them together with the SQL result

Comment: No it's not possible to have a loop in a select statement, and you can only have loops within stored programs (functions,procedures,triggers,events)

Comment: yes Kaddath the "code" way is the way to follow but i was trying to move the PHP to MYSQL in order to simplify my page.

Comment: Good idea to do it with stored procedures too.

Thank you very much for your help.