# How to extract Year together with Month from this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to show total orders by month based on a date column. May I know how to append year to the Month column?

```
select DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(<column>) - 1, 0)) AS Month,
    count(*) AS Total_Request
from <table>
group by month(<column>)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just aggregate directly by the year and month, as a single text field:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(7), <column>, 120) AS Year-Month,
    COUNT(*) AS Total_Request
FROM <table>
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(varchar(7), <column>, 120);
```

If you really want the year and three letter abbreviation for the month, you may try:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(<column>) AS Year,
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, <column>), 3) AS Month,
    COUNT(*) AS Total_Request
FROM <table>
GROUP BY
    YEAR(<column>),
    LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, <column>), 3);
```

Comment: What if I prefer it to be in readable format, Month in text form. ie. May'20

Comment: @JL_Coder I actually recommend the format I used above, because the dates will sort properly.

Comment: I am planning to serialize it into JSON object for visualization purpose.

Comment: @JL_Coder I have also given you an option for the three letter month abbreviation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Do not use `varchar` without a length specifier in SQL Server.  The default varies by context.  To avoid hard to debug errors, it should never be recommended.

Comment: @Gordon Wish I could always write code right the first time.  But, if I could do that, then I'd be you `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

From SQL Server 2012 you can use FORMAT function

```
SELECT 
     FORMAT( YourColumn, 'yyyy-MMMM')
     ,COUNT(*) AS Total_Request
FROM 
    <table>
GROUP BY 
    FORMAT( YourColumn, 'yyyy-MMMM')
```

You can also add a culture as third parameter.
Below the syntax SQL:

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

For documentation look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Is there any way to sort it ascending?

Comment: added "order by Month desc"

Comment: Add below: `ORDER BY FORMAT( YourColumn, 'yyyy-MMMM') ASC`. You can also add alias in SELECT column and use it in ORDER BY

Comment: Any idea on how to query for the last 12 months even without the data?

Comment: Seems still not able to generate months without data..

Comment: Look this post. Should help you do what you ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943405/sql-server-getting-last-x-month-average-including-missing-months