# How to exclude weeks based on Year and Week columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a [Year/Week] column, based on which I want to have a window of 12 weeks inclusive of current week. For example: If current week is Week 5, I want to show my window from Week 5 to Week 16, regardless if the current day is Monday or Friday.

I have tried setting some numbers to adjust this window in the code below, but I believe there must be a better way.

```
CREATE TABLE #DATES ([Year/Week] VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #DATES ([Year/Week]) VALUES
('2019/W01'),('2019/W02'),('2019/W03'),('2019/W04'),('2019/W05')
,('2019/W06'),('2019/W07'),('2019/W08'),('2019/W09'),('2019/W10')
,('2019/W11'),('2019/W12'),('2019/W13'),('2019/W14'),('2019/W15')
,('2019/W16'),('2019/W17'),('2019/W18'),('2019/W19'),('2019/W20')
,('2019/W21'),('2019/W22'),('2019/W23'),('2019/W24'),('2019/W25')
,('2019/W26'),('2019/W27'),('2019/W28'),('2019/W29'),('2019/W30')
,('2019/W31'),('2019/W32'),('2019/W33'),('2019/W34'),('2019/W35')

SELECT DISTINCT 
CONVERT(INT, LEFT([Year/Week], 4)) AS [Year]
,CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([Year/Week], 2)) AS [Week]
,dateadd (week, CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([Year/Week], 2)), dateadd (year, 
CONVERT(INT, LEFT([Year/Week], 4))-1900, 0)) - 4 -
       datepart(dw, dateadd (week, CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([Year/Week], 2)), 
dateadd (year, CONVERT(INT, LEFT([Year/Week], 4))-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1  AS 
[Week Date]

FROM #DATES
WHERE dateadd (week, CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([Year/Week], 2)), dateadd (year, 
CONVERT(INT, LEFT([Year/Week], 4))-1900, 0)) - 4 -
       datepart(dw, dateadd (week, CONVERT(INT, RIGHT([Year/Week], 2)), 
dateadd (year, CONVERT(INT, LEFT([Year/Week], 4))-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1 
BETWEEN GETDATE() - 3 AND GETDATE() + 81

ORDER BY [Year], [Week]
```

Comment: Why are you storing that as one string instead of two numbers?

Comment: If the data is already stored like that, it may be easier to create a second reference table where 2019/W01 is defined as 2019-01-01 startdate and 2019-01-07 EndDate. If you want to define your weeks based on the first Monday, then adjust your dates accordingly.

Comment: By the way, the [ISO 8601 standard format for a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) uses a hyphen rather than the slash seen your text: `2019-W01`. Or, optionally, in the “Basic” variation minimizing the use of delimiters, no hyhpen: `2018W01`. (I recommend using full length rather than Basic, wherever feasible.)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to have [Calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635628/1118978) for reporting purposes.

After that you can easily get same result with small query

```
select Year, Week 
from Auxiliary.Calendar 
where Date between GetDate() and DATEADD(MONTH, 4, GetDate())
```

Here is [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb96a14d0bd274b849ef4e52394ebbfa)

Comment: @shantanu This is what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using ISO weeks. You should be able to perform the comparison "alphabetically" with something like this:

```
select [Year/Week] from #DATES
where [Year/Week] between
    format(getdate() -  3, 'yyyy/\W') + format(datepart(iso_week, getdate() -  3), '0#') and
    format(getdate() + 81, 'yyyy/\W') + format(datepart(iso_week, getdate() + 81), '0#')
order by [Year/Week];
```

Make sure the week numbers match with yours.

Unfortunately I didn't think of a way to avoid repeating the date expression. Perhaps there's even something a bit more compact. An expression like this will probably be better at using an index on your `Year/Week` column.