# How to get date from WeekNumber and WeekDay

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have this dataset with WeekNo (Year and week) - WeekDayName which is the day there is data. I need to know exactly what date it is.

```
WeekNo  WeekDayName
------  -----------
201905  Mandag
201905  Mandag
201905  Mandag
201905  Tirsdag
201905  Tirsdag
201905  Tirsdag
201905  Onsdag
201905  Onsdag
201905  Onsdag
201905  Torsdag
201905  Torsdag
201905  Torsdag
201905  Fredag
201905  Fredag
201905  Fredag
```

Desired result:

```
WeekNo  WeekDayName Date
------  ----------- -----
201905  Mandag      2019-01-28
201905  Mandag      2019-01-28
201905  Mandag      2019-01-28
201905  Tirsdag     2019-01-29
201905  Tirsdag     2019-01-29
201905  Tirsdag     2019-01-29
201905  Onsdag      2019-01-30
201905  Onsdag      2019-01-30
201905  Onsdag      2019-01-30
201905  Torsdag     2019-01-31
201905  Torsdag     2019-01-31
201905  Torsdag     2019-01-31
201905  Fredag      2019-02-01
201905  Fredag      2019-02-01
201905  Fredag      2019-02-01
```

Ive tried this, but it only gives me the start of the week:

```
declare @IntWeek as varchar(20) SET @IntWeek = '201905'

SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, @@DATEFIRST, LEFT(@IntWeek,4)+'-01-01') + (cast(RIGHT(@IntWeek,2) as int)-1), @@DATEFIRST) AS StartOfWeek
```

Comment: Probably best by first creating a `[Calendar]` table with all dates of the year(s), and extra fields that can't be calculated directly via [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql). Then you can join your table to it.

Comment: @LukStorms Great idea! Why didnt I think of that. That might be a more sustainable solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may consider to have [Calendar Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5635628/1118978)

After that you can easily get result

```
select date 
from Auxiliary.Calendar 
where Year = CAST(LEFT(@IntWeek,4) as int)
  and Week = CAST(RIGHT(@IntWeek,2) as int)
  and WeekDay = 'Mondag'
```

Comment: Are you missing something? I need the dates. This just gives me one date, and basically the same result as i already have.

Comment: Yes excatly and daynumber. I dont know why I didnt came up with this, but its obviously much easier! So thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that receives 2 parameters:

> 1.- your First day of the week
>
> 2.- the day name

```
The function must do IF

IF dayName = 'Sunday'
  Return same date
Else If dayName = 'Monday
  Return Data + 1 day
```

....