# Sum previous months values for row date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL Server query to return something like:

```
Client_ID | REF_DATE | SALES | SALES_PREVIOUS_6_MONTHS | SALES_NEXT_6_MONTHS
```

But the problem is that my base date is not "Today" or something like that. But actually the "REF_DATE".

So, if a customer buys something on july/2015, I want to know how much he spent in this reference month (july/2015), the previous and next 6 months from july/2015. I need to have a line for August to and so on.

I'm using an invoice database where I have an aggregation for the month on the first day of it.

I tried using the CASE WHEN statement, but as it returns only "FALSE" for my condition, it returns 0.

```sql
SELECT
    Client_ID,
    REF_DATE,
    SUM(SALES),
    CASE 
       WHEN REF_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -6, REF_DATE) AND DATEADD(MONTH, -1, REF_DATE) 
          THEN SUM(SALES) 
          ELSE 0.0 
    END AS SALES_PREVIOUS_6_MONTHS,
    CASE 
       WHEN REF_DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, +1, REF_DATE) AND DATEADD(MONTH, +6, REF_DATE) 
          THEN SUM(SALES) 
          ELSE 0.0 
    END AS SALES_NEXT_6_MONTHS
FROM
    dbo.invoices         
GROUP BY
    Client_ID, REF_DATE
```

My desired output is something like:

```
+------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
| Client_ID  |  REF_DATE  |  SALES  |  SALES_PREVIOUS_6_MONTHS  |  SALES_NEXT_6_MONTHS |
+------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
|          1 | 01/07/2014 |       0 |                         0 |                 1234 |
|          1 | 01/08/2014 |       0 |                         0 |                 3579 |
|          1 | 01/09/2014 |       0 |                         0 |                 7035 |
|          1 | 01/10/2014 |       0 |                         0 |                11602 |
|          1 | 01/11/2014 |       0 |                         0 |                12836 |
|          1 | 01/12/2014 |       0 |                         0 |                17403 |
|          1 | 01/01/2015 |    1234 |                         0 |                24059 |
|          1 | 01/02/2015 |    2345 |                      1234 |                21714 |
|          1 | 01/03/2015 |    3456 |                      3579 |                18258 |
|          1 | 01/04/2015 |    4567 |                      7035 |                13691 |
|          1 | 01/05/2015 |    1234 |                     11602 |                12457 |
|          1 | 01/06/2015 |    4567 |                     12836 |                 7890 |
|          1 | 01/07/2015 |    7890 |                     17403 |                    0 |
|          1 | 01/08/2015 |       0 |                     24059 |                    0 |
|          1 | 01/09/2015 |       0 |                     21714 |                    0 |
|          1 | 01/10/2015 |       0 |                     18258 |                    0 |
|          1 | 01/11/2015 |       0 |                     13691 |                    0 |
|          1 | 01/12/2015 |       0 |                     12457 |                    0 |
+------------+------------+---------+---------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: You might be looking for a window function but a bit hard to tell without example data and expected results.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: why +1 and -1 a month. You tried using `DAY`?

Comment: You need to move the SUM() so it contains the CASE statement.

Comment: *"why +1 and -1 a month. You tried using DAY?"* @SebastianBrosch see expected resullt`SALES_PREVIOUS_6_MONTHS | SALES_NEXT_6_MONTHS`

Comment: @RaymondNijland - but the month starts a day later or a day earlier, not a month. right?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I'm working this way because the db has only the first day of each month.

Comment: well @SebastianBrosch the topicstarter should read mine first comment and provide example data and expected results as this question is unclear..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Please see if my edit helps

Comment: did you try @GordonLinoff 's query?

Comment: @RaymondNijland working on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a record for every client for every month:

```
SELECT Client_ID, REF_DATE, SUM(SALES),
       SUM(SUM(SALES)) OVER (PARTITION BY Client_id ORDER BY REF_DATE ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as SALES_PREVIOUS_6_MONTHS,
       SUM(SUM(SALES)) OVER (PARTITION BY Client_id ORDER BY REF_DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 6 FOLLOWING) as SALES_NEXT_6_MONTHS,
FROM dbo.invoices i  
GROUP BY Client_ID, REF_DATE;
```

If you don't have a record for each client for each month, then the logic is a bit more complicated.

Comment: The invoices table have different lines for different products for the same client in a month. When you say complicated do mean subquery?

Comment: @RicardoPedrotti Gordon most likely means that you will have to generate some kind of  [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql) for the missing values and use LEFT JOIN

Comment: @RicardoPedrotti . . . That is okay.  There just needs to be one row per month per client after the aggregation for the windowing clause to do what you want.