# SQL : How to show all dates between a given range?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, left-join, user-defined-functions

I have a table-valued function which returns something like this:

[image]

Now, I have a date range as a parameter, let's say **'2020-03-01' and '2020-04-15'** 
What I want is to also add a column that displays all the date from **'2020-03-01' up to '2020-04-15'**
It should look like this:

```
    Overtime          | Status               | DTR        | DATE_START    |   DATE
    1.  NULL          | NULL                 | NULL       | NULL          | 2020-03-01
    2.  NULL          | NULL                 | NULL       | NULL          | 2020-03-02
    ...
    ...
    ...
    30. 6:32PM-9:32PM | Pending For Approval | NULL       | 2020-03-30    | 2020-03-30
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

My code goes like this ,,**Dont mind the 95476237** :

```
SELECT CAST(a.IndividualDate as date)
FROM DateRange('d', @start, @end) as a 
LEFT JOIN support.dbo.overtimeReport('95476237', @start, @end) as b on CAST(a.IndividualDate as date) = CAST(b.DATE_START as date)
```

As a result, I only got this,

[image]

**UPDATE: Small mistake, I forgot to mention the rest of columns in the SELECT statement. Thanks to @iamdave**

Comment: You'll need to use a Calendar Table for this, then join the calendar table with the results you require. See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql).

Comment: If you require further assistance with this, please provide sample data and expected results, then we'll assist...

Comment: @Birel I already provided a sample data, expected output, and the actual output. Respectively

Comment: Thank you @amm, the sample data you provided is a screenshot. In order for us to easily assist you, steer clear from using screenshots, except with your expected results...

Comment: You have only included one column in your `select` statement which is why you are only getting one column in your output...

Comment: @iamdave That's why I used left join in it.

Comment: A [calendar table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table) is definitely what you want here. Build one of those, and you likely have your answer too.

Comment: @amm You need to specify *all* columns you want returned in your `select`.  You have made them available through your `left join`, but you have not actually added any of them to your `select`.

Comment: @iamdave Thanks man! I thought left join automatically displays all the matched records.

Comment: It must be the case that you do something like `SELECT *` or select multiple columns (`SELECT x,y,z`) from your  TVF. To write only one column in your select list and then come on SO and ask why you're only getting one column in the output isn't *really* a question..

Comment: JOINs have nothing to do with choosing which columns to display ("which column" is driven by the SELECT list) - they're more about choosing which related rows to display!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add *all* the columns you want to output into your `select` statement.  The rest of the query seems to be okay (ignoring all the bad smells of selecting from a TVF and using `cast` on both sides of your `join` criteria...):

```
SELECT b.Overtime
      ,b.Status
      ,b.DTR
      ,DATE_STARTCAST(a.IndividualDate as date) AS [Date]
FROM DateRange('d', @start, @end) as a 
LEFT JOIN support.dbo.overtimeReport('95476237', @start, @end) as b
    ON CAST(a.IndividualDate as date) = CAST(b.DATE_START as date)
```

Also, please don't alias your tables with `a`, `b`, `c` etc.  Use something that actually tells anyone reading this code which table is being referred to.

Comment: Thanks man! I thought left join automatically displays all the matched records.