# How can i create a Date table in SQL that will automatically fill itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datatable, dimensions

I wanna create a table in SQL with the following 4 colums: id, year, month and day. But i wanna fill this colums automatically from the year of 2012 to 2020. What is the best way to do this? i googled but i couln't really find a solution. For example i want the table to show the following information.

```
ID  year  Month Day
1   2013   1     2
2   2013   1     3
3   2013   1     4
4   2013   1     5
```

Comment: Please add the tag of the database you use, for example: Oracle, MySQL, SQLServer...

Comment: In SQL, you first create the table, then INSERT the data. You can use a recursive cte to insert all these dates.

Comment: This looks like a good article... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: More often than not, these are referred to as `calendar table`. There are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: Aslo here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql and here https://gist.github.com/pimbrouwers/c8613ad33edbe22078e1c55c862ee7f8

Comment: I use this [tvf](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/a-daterange-table-valued-function) it's flexible and quick

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for loops, cursors or recursive CTEs... It's as easy as the following.

```
    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100
        cte_Calendar (dt) AS (
            SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01', '2020-12-31') + 1)
                CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '2012-01-01'))
            FROM
                cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b                                                    -- 10,000
            )
    SELECT
        ID = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01', c.dt) + 1,
        [Year] = YEAR(c.dt),
        [Month] = MONTH(c.dt),
        [Day] = DAY(c.dt)
    FROM
        cte_Calendar c;
GO
```

Or you can use it to populate a permanent table...

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.YMD', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.YMD; END;
    GO
    
    CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.YMD (
            ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
                CONSTRAINT pk_YMD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID),
            [Year] int NOT NULL,
            [Month] tinyint NOT NULL,
            [Day] tinyint NOT NULL 
        );
    GO
    
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100
        cte_Calendar (dt) AS (
            SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '2012-01-01', '2020-12-31') + 1)
                CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, '2012-01-01'))
            FROM
                cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b                                                    -- 10,000
            )
    INSERT tempdb.dbo.YMD (Year, Month, Day)
    SELECT 
        [Year] = YEAR(c.dt),
        [Month] = MONTH(c.dt),
        [Day] = DAY(c.dt)
    FROM
        cte_Calendar c;
GO
    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SELECT
        YMD.ID,
        YMD.Year,
        YMD.Month,
        YMD.Day
    FROM
        tempdb.dbo.YMD;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **VBoka** suggestion, try this:

```
create table calendar(
    id int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
    ano int not null,
    mes int not null,
    dia int not null
)

declare @startdate date, @enddate date, @num_days int
set @startdate = '2012-01-01'
set @num_days = 3287 --number of days bewtween jan 2012 and dez 2020 https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html
set @enddate = dateadd(d, @num_days, @startdate)

while @startdate <= @enddate
    begin
        insert into calendar (ano,mes,dia)
            select year(@startdate), month(@startdate), day(@startdate)

        set @startdate = dateadd(dd, 1, @startdate)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE and no datetime functions:

```
if object_id('Calendar_tb','U') is null
    create table Calendar_tb (
        id int identity(1,1) not null,
        [year] smallint, [month] tinyint, [day] tinyint
    )

declare @tb table (yy smallint, mm tinyint, dd tinyint);
with
CTE_y as (
    select 2012 as nyear
    union all
    select nyear + 1 from CTE_y where nyear < 2020
),
CTE_m as (
    select 1 as nmonth
    union all
    select nmonth + 1 from CTE_m where nmonth < 12
),
CTE_d as (
    select 1 as nday
    union all
    select nday + 1 from cte_d where nday < 31
)
insert @tb
select nyear, nmonth, nday from CTE_d, CTE_m, CTE_y

delete from @tb
where   (dd>30 and mm in (4, 6, 9, 11))
    or  (dd>29 and mm = 2)
    or  (dd>28 and mm = 2 and not
            -- leap year
            (yy%400=0 or (yy%4=0 and yy%100!=0)))

truncate table Calendar_tb

insert Calendar_tb
select * from @tb order by 1, 2, 3

select * from Calendar_tb
```

Comment: Considering how bad recursive CTEs perform, especially for reads, you should consider practicing to avoid them... even for small stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime2, @enddate datetime2, @days int

CREATE TABLE #tbl_dates 
(ID int identity(1,1), 
[Year] int, 
[Month] int, 
[Day] int)

SET @startdate = '01/01/0001'
SET @enddate   = CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),101)
SET @days      = DATEDIFF(Day,@startdate,@enddate)+1

INSERT #tbl_dates ([year])
SELECT TOP (@days) NULL
FROM sys.tables a 
JOIN sys.tables b on a.object_id = a.object_id
-- a.object_id = a.object_id is on purpose.

UPDATE #tbl_dates 
SET [year]  = DATEPART(year, DATEADD(d,ID-1,@startdate)),
    [Month] = DATEPART(month,DATEADD(d,ID-1,@startdate)),
    [Day]   = DATEPART(day,  DATEADD(d,ID-1,@startdate))

SELECT ID, 
    [Year] = RIGHT('0000'+CAST([year] as varchar(4)),4),
    [Month], 
    [Day]
FROM #tbl_dates 
ORDER BY ID

/*
USE A TABLE WITH ENOUGH RECORDS TO HANDLE YOUR NEED (OR JOIN MULTIPLE TABLES). THERE ARE PROBABLY BETTER WAYS BUT TO KNOCK THIS OUT QUICKLY I JOINED MY sys.table to sys.tables ON object_id (a. = a.) TO GET 4,024,036 RECORDS. ON 12/05/2023 I NEEDED 738,859 RECORDS TO GO ALL THE WAY BACK TO 01/01/0001.
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**