# How to list the months between a start date and end date by MEMBER_ID in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of Member IDs and they have a START_DATE and END_DATE as is below.

| MEMBER_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-31 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-28 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-03-31 |

But I need a table that lists each month between the minimum start date and maximum end date like this - **THIS IS MY DESIRED OUTPUT**:

| MEMBER_ID | START_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 |

I have tried the below code:

```
 WITH TEST AS
   (SELECT MEMBER_ID
   ,MIN(START_DATE) AS MIN_START_DATE
   ,MAX(END_DATE) AS MAX_END_DATE
    FROM < INSERT TABLE NAME >
    GROUP BY MEMBER_ID,
         START_DATE,
         END_DATE),

CTE AS (
  select MEMBER_ID,
         dateadd(day, 1 - day(MIN_START_DATE), MIN_START_DATE) as som,
         eomonth(MAX_END_DATE) as eom
   FROM TEST
   GROUP BY MEMBER_ID,
   dateadd(day, 1 - day(MIN_START_DATE), MIN_START_DATE),
   eomonth(MAX_END_DATE)
  union all
  select MEMBER_ID, dateadd(month, 1, som), eomonth(dateadd(month, 1, som))
  from CTE
  where dateadd(month, 1, som) < eom)

 select DISTINCT MEMBER_ID, som
 from CTE
```

But the result I get is as below:

| MEMBER_ID | som |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 |

It's not returning the last month that should be 2023-03-01.

I'm probably doing something wrong in the recursive CTE. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the first of each `END DATE`? Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I need the first of each month between the minimum START DATE (1/1/2023 in this example) and the maximum END_DATE (3/31/2023 in this example). The second table shows my desired output. I understand that the first of each end date would work in this example, but it will not for most situations.

Comment: The second table is my desired output. I will make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively simple if you have a calendar table in your environment.

Even a simple one that is a list of dates would be beneficial. An example:

```
CREATE TABLE CAL (cal_date date);
with dates ([Date]) as (
    Select convert(date,'2020-01-01') as [Date] 
    union all 
    Select dateadd(day, 1, [Date])
    from dates
    where [Date] <= '2025-12-31' 
)
INSERT INTO CAL
select [Date]
from dates
option (maxrecursion 32767)
```

With this you have a table to which you can join to get all the first_of_month's between your two dates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MEMBER_ID,
  cal.first_of_month as START_DATE
FROM TEST
   INNER JOIN (SELECT cal_date as first_of_month FROM CAL WHERE DAY(cal_date) = 1) as cal
      ON cal.first_of_month BETWEEN TEST.START_DATE AND TEST.END_DATE
```

[DBFiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/l4zpEFFp)

[A good article with a great write up on creating a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

[Also, some good answers on stackoverflow for creating a date dimension or calendar table in your sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql)

Comment: Do be careful using a recursive cte for this kind of thing. It can become a challenge from a performance perspective because it is basically using a loop. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

Comment: I was able to make this work - thank you very much. The data I'm working with only applies to the first 3 months of 2023, so I only needed the "calendar" for that part of the year, which I'm sure helps with performance.

Comment: To Sean Lange's point, the recursive CTE in this example should only be a one-time thing to create and populate a proper calendar/date-dimension table. I feel like every database should have a calendar table built on day-one since date dimension attributes are so useful. If instead you are generating these dates every time you want to run this then @SeanLange's approach with generate series is superior.

Comment: +100 for having a calendar table and/or a numbers table in every database.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using an ad-hoc tally/numbers table.

You may notice the `TOP 500`, you certainly can pick a more reasonable value, but be sure to leave a little wiggle room

**Example**

```
Select Distinct 
       A.MEMBER_ID
      ,NewValue = dateadd(month,n,start_date)     
 From YourTable A
 Join (
        Select Top 500 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
      ) B
    on N<=datediff(month,Start_Date,End_Date)
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun I put this together using generate_series which is only available in Azure or 2022. It is lightning fast if you are on a new enough version.

```
with DateRange as
(
    select a.MEMBER_ID
        , MonthCount = datediff(month, min(start_date), max(end_date))
        , StartDate = min(start_date)
    from Members a
    group by a.MEMBER_ID
)
select MEMBER_ID
    , dateadd(month, x.value - 1, StartDate)
from DateRange
cross apply generate_series(1, MonthCount + 1) x
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not on a new enough version, unfortunately, but this is interesting.