Aggregate financial transactions into monthly balances
I have these financial transactions (name of client, date of transactions and debit and credit amount). There can be multiple transactions for the same client on the same date.
 Name   Date    Debit   Credit
 A  2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 10  0
 A  2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 9   0
 A  2021-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 11  0
 A  2021-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 0   50
 A  2021-04-01 00:00:00.0000000 30  0
 B  2021-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 10  0
 B  2022-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 0   12
 B  2022-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 0   50
 B  2024-04-01 00:00:00.0000000 3   0

I would like the balances for each client for each month. (It's fine if the there are missing years / months for when there were no transactions but ideally the result should be gapless.)
Below results with gaps (e.g. gap between B 2021/1 and B 2022/2)
Name    Year    Month   balance
A   2021    1   -19
A   2021    2   -30
A   2021    3   20
A   2021    4   -10
B   2021    1   -10
B   2022    2   2
B   2022    3   52
B   2024    4   49

Here results without gaps (... elided year/month with no transactions)
 Name    Year    Month   balance
 A   2021    1   -19 -- start from the very first transaction
 A   2021    2   -30
 A   2021    3   20
 A   2021    4   -10
 A   2021    5   -10 -- no transaction for 2021/5 so repeat the previous balance
 ...                -- show all year/months to 2024-03
 A   2024    4   -10 -- all the way to the current month
 
 B   2021    1   -10
 B   2021    2   -10 -- no transaction
 B   2021    3   -10 -- no transaction
 ...                 -- show all year/months to 2021-12
 B   2022    1   -10 -- no transaction
 B   2022    2   2   
 B   2022    3   52  
 B   2022    4   52  -- no transaction
 B   2022    5   52  -- no transaction
 ...                 -- show all year/months to 2024-03
 B   2024    3   49  -- no transaction
 B   2024    4   49

I managed to do this in 2 steps.

First group per client, year and month.
Then for each group sum all the preceding transactions to get the balance.

Here the SQL
 DECLARE @MyTransactions TABLE (
    [Name] nvarchar(10),
    [Date] datetime2,
    [Debit] decimal,
    [Credit] decimal
 )
 
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('A','2021-01-01',10,0)
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('A','2021-02-01',11,0)
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('A','2021-03-01',0,50)
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('A','2021-04-01',30,0)
 
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('B','2021-01-01',10,0)
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('B','2022-02-01',0,12)
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('B','2022-03-01',0,50)
 INSERT INTO @MyTransactions ([Name],[Date],[Debit],[Credit]) VALUES ('B','2024-04-01',3,0)
 
 
 DECLARE @MyGroups TABLE (
    [Name] nvarchar(10),
    [Year] int,
    [Month] int
 )
 
 
 -- 1. first group per client, year and month
 INSERT INTO @MyGroups ([Name],[Year],[Month])
 SELECT [Name], DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]), DATEPART(MONTH, [Date])
 FROM @MyTransactions
 GROUP BY [Name],DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]), DATEPART(MONTH, [Date])
 
 -- 2. now for each group sum all the preceding transactions to get the balance
 SELECT 
    G.[Name], G.[Year], G.[Month],  SUM(ISNULL(T.Credit,0) - ISNULL(T.Debit,0))             
 FROM @MyGroups G
 JOIN @MyTransactions T ON 
    T.[Name] = G.[Name] 
    AND 
    (
    (DATEPART(YEAR, T.[Date]) = G.[Year] AND DATEPART(MONTH, T.[Date]) <= G.[Month])
    OR
    (DATEPART(YEAR, T.[Date]) < G.[Year])
    )
 GROUP BY G.[Name], G.[Year], G.[Month]

Questions

Is there a way to do this more elegantly, e.g. in one step without a temporary grouping table?
How to ensure that there are no gaps between the dates?


how to ensure that there are no gaps between the dates? Do you have a calendar table ?

You should definitely use a calendar table to fill the "missing" months. It's very unpleasant without. Just search for that in the web. There are many articles how to do that, for example also on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635594/how-to-create-a-calendar-table-for-100-years-in-sql

With a calendar table this is not so difficult, than you just select on the daterange in the calendar table and join with your actual data.
Here is a DBFiddle example on how to do that
Assuming the calendar table is called tblMonths the query looks like this
select t.[Name], 
       m.year, m.Month, 
       sum(sum(t.Credit) - sum(t.Debit)) over(partition by name order by m.year, m.month) Balance
from   ( select mm.Year, mm.Month, min(mm.[Date]) as [Date]
         from   tblMonths mm
         where  mm.[Date] >= '20210101' and mm.[Date] < '20240401'
         group by mm.Year, mm.Month
       ) m
  -- use the left join for gapless, and the inner join for having gaps
  left join MyTransactions t on m.[Date] = t.[Date]
  --inner join MyTransactions t on m.[Date] = t.[Date]
  
group by m.year, m.Month, t.[Name]
order by m.Year, m.Month


You can simply use SUM()OVER() window function to get your desired result like below
(Please explain "How to ensure that there are no gaps between the dates?")
Query:
select Name,DATEPART(YEAR,[date]) [Year],DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) [Month],
  SUM(Credit-Debit) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR,[date]) ,DATEPART(MONTH,[Date])) Balance
  from @MyTransactions

Output:



Name
Year
Month
Balance




A
2021
1
-10


A
2021
2
-21


A
2021
3
29


A
2021
4
-1


B
2021
1
-10


B
2022
2
2


B
2022
3
52


B
2024
4
49



fiddle

You don't need DATEPART, it's enough to write YEAR(date) and MONTH(date) : https://dbfiddle.uk/OLQh4imO

Thanks @JonasMetzler. Appreciate your valuable input.
